# Conflict between 'editable' and Mezzanine form in Django/Mezzanine template

Tags: django, django-templates, mezzanine

I'm getting a conflict between editable fields and a mezzanine form (i.e. a standard form created in the admin).

When I make the page title 'editable', the form at the bottom renders a field to edit the title instead of the actual form.  As the editable fields only show when you are logged in, this is only an issue when I am logged in.

If I remove 'editable' on the title the form renders as it should when logged in and logged out.

The code that causes the problem:

```
<h1>{% editable page.form.title %}{{ page.form.title }}{% endeditable %}</h1>

{% if request.GET.sent %}
    <div class="well">
        {% editable page.form.response %}
        {{ page.form.response|richtext_filter|safe }}
        {% endeditable %}
    </div>
{% else %}
    {% with page.form as page_form %}
        {% editable page_form.content %}
            {{ page_form.content|richtext_filter|safe }}
        {% endeditable %}
        <form method="post">
            {% fields_for form %}
            <input type="submit" value="{{ page.form.button_text }}">
        </form>
    {% endwith %}
{% endif %}
```

Any ideas very much appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed on IRC - there's a name collision in the templates, with a fix in Mezzanine pending.